# WooCommerce Dynamic Surchage based on radio button in checkout

Tags: php, ajax, radio-button, woocommerce

How do I get a Radio Button Group to update a surchage listed in the checkout total on a WooCommerce Checkout page when one is selected, then the other. The selection of Radio Button A needs to add  0.05 percent as a surcharge where as, Radio Button B would add 0.10 percent.

I know that I can add a static surcharge with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

// $percentage is what will change based on which button is selected A or B
// however this is not executed after the page is loaded
$percentage = 0.05;

$surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Service Fee', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by having the AJAX, handle the button change and call a PHP callback that set WC->session->set variable.  Then in the AJAX is issued a location.reload which forced functions.php to reload.  Inside of my surcharge filter I then checked for the session variable and added the fee or not based on the session value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would get you started. I don't think it will automatically add the fee, but I haven't tested it and it is just an idea:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if ( typeof wc_checkout_form === 'undefined' || ) {
        return false;
    }

    $checkout_form = $( 'form.checkout' );
    $checkout_form.on( 'change', '.your_radio_buttons_class', function(){
        wc_checkout_form.wc_checkout_form();
    });

});
```

I believe you will need to utilize the [checkout script](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js), so you want to ensure that your custom script is loaded after `checkout.js`.